# Java rx - should you use Single<List<Item>> or rather Observabe<Item>

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a question regarding which style of java rx better to use. Let's say you have a web service, that returns a List of items, which we will represent by a list. Now most tutorials seem to handle this by emitting single values through observable, for example:

```
 Observable<Todo> todoObservable = Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<Todo>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<Todo> emitter) throws Exception {
            try {
                List<Todo> todos = RxJavaUnitTest.this.getTodos();
                for (Todo todo : todos) {
                    emitter.onNext(todo);
                }
                emitter.onComplete();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                emitter.onError(e);
            }
        }
    });
```

However you could handle the situation through Single, emitting a list:

```
Single.create(new SingleOnSubscribe<List<Todo>>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(SingleEmitter<List<Todo>> emitter) throws Exception {
            List<Todo> todos = RxJavaUnitTest.this.getTodos();
            emitter.onSuccess(todos);
        }
    })
```

Is there an advantage to emit per item over the whole list? It seems to me that mostly you would want to combine the items back to the list in the ui...

Comment: `Single` is best used if this list that you are getting doesn't have paging. i.e. it supports a single page where all the data is queried at once and utilised. `Observable` would be the way to go, if you had a stream of lists that are being read from the service one page at a time.

Comment: Even then, you would probably just pass parameter to the Single - the page you wanted and expect the list for that?

Comment: I would use a `BehaviorSubject.switchMap{}` which is of type `Observable` for paging because when I call `BehaviorSubject.onNext(page)` it automatically triggers the subscription call without having to write boilerplate. When there are no further pages you call `BehaviorSubject.onComplete()` to perform action on complete. In case of using a `Single` you need to continuously create subscription calls writing boilerplate for each page instead of leaving a hook. Of course either way you would need to `dispose` them upon end of lifecycle else they would cause leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single would make more sense if you're getting the data from the webservice. You're only expecting one instance of response mostly.

Observable would only be beneficial for you if you expect the web service request to be a stream. For most Single would give you what you need with less overhead.

Comment: Can you elaborate "if you expect the web service request to be a stream" by an example use case please? 
I guess what you mean is that there would be delays between passing each "Todo" to the emittor?